# Given a probability distribution find the corresponding random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a sequence of Borel-probability measures $\{\nu_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, does there exist a sequence of independent random variables on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathrm{P})$ with $X_k:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathrm{P}_{X_k}=\mathrm{P}X_k^{-1} = \nu_k$? I've seen the corresponding result for measures on $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't see how to extend it to finitely many dimensions.

Comment: A very general result on the existence of collections of random variable with prescribed finite dimensional distributions is Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem. You can find it everywhere: in books, on Wikipedia etc.

Comment: Ah yes this is perfect, thank you :)